# SQL - Assignment in CASE inside a SELECT in a Recursive Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, case, variable-assignment

I'm creating a SQL Server 2008 query that would output the list of employees in a company along with the team they are on with an additional column.

Example of the org tree:

```
Level 0: CEO
Level 1: A, B, and C
Level 2:
    For A:1,2,3
    For B:4,5,6
    For C:7,8,9
```

In my resulting set, I should see three columns -- name, level (of the tree), and team. For 1,2, and 3, I'd see 'A' as their team and 2 as the level. For 4,5, and 6, 'B' and 2 for the level and so on.

I'm using a recursive query to navigate the tree (no problems there), but since I need to "carry" the team name down the query (in case there's a level 8 -- it should still show the person in level 1 they report to), I'm doing this:

```
(...)
UNION ALL
-- Recursive Member Definition
-- in here level increments one each time, and the team should output the child
-- of the top manager
SELECT  A.treenodeid, A.parentnodeid, A.email, LEVEL+1, team = 
                                    CASE LEVEL
                                        When 1 then SET @salead = A.Email
                                        Else @salead
                                    END
   FROM XX as A 
  INNER JOIN TeamsTable as B on A.parentnodeid = b.treenodeID
```

Since **I'm trying to use a CASE to check if the level is 1** (to update the team name to whatever the team lead's email name is), SQL keeps saying that in the case I have "**Incorrect syntax near SET**".

Is it possible to do this sort of assignment in a CASE? I've looked around and haven't found if this can work with my recursive case.

Here's all the query (assuming that the root is 'JohnSmith'):

```
WITH TeamsTable (treenodeid, parentnodeid, email, Level, team)
AS
( 
    -- Anchor - Level starts with 0, and the team is empty for the top manager
    SELECT treenodeid,parentnodeid,email,0,''       
     FROM XX WHERE email = 'JohnSmith'

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive Member Definition - in here level increments one each time, and the team should output the child of the top manager
    SELECT
        A.treenodeid, A.parentnodeid, A.email, LEVEL+1, team = 
                                CASE LEVEL
                                    When 1 then SET @salead = A.Email
                                    Else @salead
                                END
    FROM XX as A 
    INNER JOIN TeamsTable as B on A.parentnodeid = b.treenodeID
)

-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT *
FROM TeamsTable
```

Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the variable at all? I don't see it being used subsequently

Comment: this should be added as a comment, not an answer

Comment: I use it in the Select * from TeamsTable -- it should report in each row: the emailName of the person, the level of the person, and who their leader (salead) is.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem from the bottom up, not from the top down.

You've not said what teams A, B, C or CEO should be in, so I've made that up.

I've also included the sample data in a usable form:

```
create table Org (
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(10) not null,
    ParentID int null
)
go
insert into Org (ID,Name,ParentID) values
(1,'CEO',null),
(2,'A',1),
(3,'B',1),
(4,'C',1),
(5,'1',2),
(6,'2',2),
(7,'3',2),
(8,'4',3),
(9,'5',3),
(10,'6',3),
(11,'7',4),
(12,'8',4),
(13,'9',4)
```

Query:

```
;With AllPeople as (
    select ID,ID as LastParentID,ParentID as NextParentID, CASE WHEN ParentID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Level
    from Org
    union all
    select ap.ID,ap.NextParentID,o.ParentID,Level + 1
    from
        AllPeople ap
            inner join
        Org o
            on
                ap.NextParentID = o.ID and
                o.ParentID is not null
), Roots as (
    select ID from Org where ParentID is null
), RootedPeople as (
    select * from AllPeople where NextParentID is null or NextParentID in (select ID from Roots)
), Names as (
    select
        oself.Name,
        oteam.Name as Team,
        Level
    from
        RootedPeople rp
            inner join
        Org oself on rp.ID = oself.ID
            left join
        Org oteam on rp.LastParentID = oteam.ID
)
select * from Names
```

Result:

```
Name       Team       Level
---------- ---------- -----------
CEO        CEO        0
A          A          1
B          B          1
C          C          1
9          C          2
8          C          2
7          C          2
6          B          2
5          B          2
4          B          2
3          A          2
2          A          2
1          A          2
```

Explanation of the CTEs:

- `AllPeople` is a recursive query that climbs up the organisation tree until it reaches the root. We use two columns (`LastParentID` and `NextParentID`) to track two levels of the hierarchy - because, apparently, once we reach the root, we want the level before that.
- `Roots` finds all of the people who don't have a parent. It's how we identify the rows from `AllPeople` that were complete, in,
- `RootedPeople` where we find rows which never successfully found any parents, or where the recursion had reached the top of the tree.
- `Names` and finally we join back to the `Org` table to assign names to individuals and teams. This one isn't necessary - it could be the final query by itself.

Note also that, due to the recursive way the `AllPeople` CTE is built, we calculate the levels as we go - every time we recurse, we add one to the `Level` that this row represents.